# SERP - Google Rich Snippets showing the wrong date for updated post

Tags: google-search, search-results, rich-snippets, dates

When I update my post, changing the date of publication, Google News reads me the right date and Google SERP classic not (as you can see in the pictures).

[image]

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
<p style="color:red"><b>Published:</b> 
    <time itemprop="datePublished" datetime="<?php the_time('c');?>"> 
    <?php the_modified_date();?> </time></b> 

- <b>Modified:</b> <time itemprop="dateModified" datetime="<?php the_modified_date('c');?>"> 
   <?php the_modified_date();?> at <?php the_modified_time('G:i');?></time></b>
</p></div>
```

Comment: It takes time for the regular googlebot to fetch and reindex your page. Search engines are ***NOT*** real-time. You can always use the Fetch as Google and Submit to Index in Google Search Console, even then it will take 1-2 days for the change to take place.

Comment: Hi closetnoc, The post is updated but only in the title, so presumably google has already passed on the post. In addition, why in the "google news" the post is updated with the date and in the title?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with landing pages. The problem in my case was that Google was showing the publication date of embedded media I had on the page.

Does your page show a video of any sort? If so, check the publication date of that video and see if it corresponds with the publication date.

If this was your problem and you want to learn more you can check out my blog post for full info:

http://cgrundy.com/solving-an-incorrect-publication-date-in-the-serps/

Answer (score 1):

My pages are clear video (at least apparently) and other dates. In my case google writes the date of first publication. To me the code is the same as yours, the dates in my template are these:

and then in the content:

23 November 2016

The date view on google SERP instead is 4 hours ago (or the first date of publication). If it worked would have to write 30 minutes ago.